# Send a picture with Email and upload it automatically

Tags: php, email, upload, attachment, image

I know that Iphone doesn't allow file uploads via web on safari, so i want to test another method.

Is there any way i can as a user send an email with a photo as attachment to a specific email (lets say uploads@domain.com) and then let it automatically upload the photo to a webserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you either have incoming email piped directly into a script (e.g. with [procmail](http://www.procmail.org/)) or you periodically (e.g. with [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)) poll a mailbox (e.g. over [IMAP](http://php.net/imap)) looking for new messages.

Then you just need to parse the mail, extract the image, and copy it to wherever you want to copy it to.

Make sure you have some kind of sensible authentication scheme in place though.

Comment: Okay, I know what you are saying is right but isn't there any tutorial about that? If not is there any way you can do it with cPanel?

Comment: I'm not aware of any tutorial, but I've never looked for one. Each step is simple enough. cPanel probably (I've never looked, it is a laughably expensive piece of software that I've never seen the need to use) has an interface to configure cron, but I doubt it has a built in "Take all attachments sent to an email address and put them in a directory" feature.

Answer (score 0):

Sure there are quite a few solutions here. You can either fire a script whenever a mail server receives an email, poll on a regular basis or use a third part service. I wrote a blog post about [receiving email in ruby and rails](http://steve.dynedge.co.uk/2010/09/07/incoming-email-in-rails-3-choosing-the-right-approach/). Almost all of the ideas can be taken into PHP and I have done so before as an experiment.